# How can we get top scroll position in Flutter if we are using scrollable_positioned_list package?

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, widget

I am using `scrollable_positioned_list` package in my Flutter project but not able to get scroll top position to load and prepend records.

https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list

I'd like to use a scrollbar to display the scroll position for flutter web. ItemScrollController is not ScrollController so I can't wrap my ScrollablePositionedList with a Scrollbar.

I am facing the this issue to load history records. Without getting scroll's top position eg. zero "0" how can I call history records to prepend list? `ScrollController` has such feature but `scrollable_positioned_list` widget does not have such feature. any suggestion? Thanks a lot.